# Stop background scrolling after player death animation has finished

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Hi I am creating an 2D endless runner.
The background has 2 animations - Scroll and stopScroll
When the character collides and dies I want to do the following

1. enable death animation - this is happening
2. stop the timer - if I do so, all animations stop
3. stop the background scrolling - this is happening although it happens before the death animation finishes and it jumps back to the fist frame. I want the background to stop relative to the where the character died.
4. Destroy the character - this is happening but before the animations are completed.
   I think I need to use Coroutine but dont know how?

Please Help!

Here is my updated code as suggested

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Obstacle(Clone)")
    {
        StartCoroutine (DoMyThings(other.gameObject, this.gameObject, false));
    }
}

IEnumerator DoMyThings(GameObject obstacle, GameObject player, bool ninjaObjBool)
{
    ninjaObj = ninjaObjBool;
    Destroy (obstacle);
    animator.SetBool("dead", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.2f);
    Destroy (player);
    Time.timeScale=0;
    //timerIsStopped = true;
    yield break;
}
```

Background Animation
I have duplicated a bg sprite and aligned them side by side. The RHS sprite is a child of LHS sprite in the hierarchy. Then I click on the LHS bg sprite -> windows->Animation.
Use add curve to transform the bg on the X axis to get it moving infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not a good practice to find gameobject in Update(). Creating an instance of it might be expected. You can do this like-

```
private Ninja ninjaClass;
.....
void Awake(){ //You can do it in Start() too if there is no problem it causes
    ninjaClass = GameObject.Find("Ninja").GetComponent<Ninja>();
}

//Now in Update(),

void Update(){
    if(!ninjaClass.ninjaObj){
        animator.SetBool("stopScroll", true);
    }
}
```

Now, OnCollisionEnter2D(), you are setting the Time.timeScale = 0 which will stop every gameobject in the scene that is time dependent (it is good for pausing game). There are many ways to execute the happenings (1.2.3.4). It will be better if you provide codes to show how you are animating and using the timer. But as you mentioned coroutine, i'll show you an example-

```
float timer = 0.0f;
float bool timeIsStopped = false;
.........
void Update(){
    if(!timeIsStopped){timer += Time.deltaTime;}
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Obstacle(Clone)")
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoMyThings(other.gameObject, this.gameObject, false));
    }
}

IEnumerator DoMyThings(GameObject obstacle, GameObject player, bool ninjaObjBool){
    ninjaObj = ninjaObjBool;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    animator.SetBool("dead", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
    Destroy(obstacle);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    timeIsStopped = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    Destroy(player);
    yield break;
}
```

Hope it will help you to get the idea how to implement your codes.

Comment: this is great, finally I understand Coroutine and it helps me accomplish (1,2 and 4). But my background still does not pause where I want it to. I think I need to look up the best way to implement infinite scrolling backgrounds. Thanks anyways. I am going to add details regarding how I animate my background.

Comment: actually, i removed the script on the background and stopped the time via timeScale and now the BG works perfectly fine. Thanks again. I am going to update my code and it would be very kind of you if you could review it once.

Comment: Welcome. Of course I will, as soon as I get free time :)

Comment: Damn, you just almost copy-pasted the codes. That's not gonna work. I meant to give an example. If you destroy this.gameObject before the completion of the coroutine, you will never be able to execute the rest of the codes. Destroying the gameObject (in your case, player), should be the last thing to happen after all your codes have time to execute. You can destroy it after a time duration too. Just like Destroy(player, 3.0f); //Destroy the player after 3 secs. And there are lot of examples out there for 2D infinite background. You should try some. Don't just do windows->Animation. Use codes.

Comment: But I am able to achieve all that I wanted to. I think this is a quick fix as I am not working on a "REAL" project but I get your point. I will look into how best can a 2D scrolling be implemented. Thanks for the help